# Simple Html Dom insert TR in parsed HTML table

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I successfully parsed HTML table from another URL. However, what I am trying to do is I want to insert a TR within the parsed HTML table. So once the page is loaded, the HTML table will consist of the parsed table plus the TR I am inserting like after 5th or 6th row.

I tried the code below but it replaces the 5 index row of the parsed table

```
<?php 
require "simple_html_dom.php";

$html = file_get_html('http://example.com');

foreach($html->find('table.table-test') as $element){
    foreach($html->find('table.table-test tr[5]') as $injectedTR){
        $injectedTR->outertext = '<tr><td colspan="3">test</td></tr>';

    }
    echo $element;
}
?>
```

I was also thinking to parse the table into two parts, like from row 0 to 5 and I add a  the I parse the rest, but I have no clue how to do that. Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how well SimpleHTMLDom deals with being able to manipulate the page.  Normally I tend to use DOMDocument and XPath to do something like this.

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you for your reply. Please if you have any tuto for DOMDocument about how to achieve that, please share the link